# All comments deleted on a question + On question closing

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I made a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228036/what-does-this-code-output-a-smiley-face/19228070#19228070) after it was closed (later reopened though). The comment basically expressed my feelings about closing that question. If I remember correctly I stated it like this:

> Why the hell was this question closed? I feel that lately more and more questions are closed without a reason. How this question can be "unclear what is asked for" if it has such a cool answer below already. Gosh, some people misuse their powers here.

People reacted to that. Lots of upvotes and some "explanations" why it has been closed. A while ago I checked the thread again and what a surprise - all the comments, mine included, were deleted?! Allright, now you would probably expect me to start complaining about that being a bit big-brotherish. Well, I won't do that (except I kinda have done already xD).

What I really mind are closed-question categories (close reasons). That closed question was in fact pretty clear. The problem was that the person wasn't really worried about "proper ways" of asking:

> "The answer? A SMILEY FACE (WTF!?) - Not joking, the answer actually
>   is a smiley face..."

I simply think that the categories are too tight and do not suit all the cases. I would be glad if the people closing the question would have an option to state the Main Reason (the reason that will be displayed in the grey bar) themselves if they want.

Alternatively, there could be a way to talk to some person that participated in closing my question so that I can get more info what is wrong with the question and also explain myself if needed. I think moderators would think twice then :).

To the end of this post, I am starting to think that the problems are also generated by the following categories:

- unclear what you're asking
- too broad

Such questions will mostly get no answers and people/moderators might say in the comments what is wrong with the question so that it can get answers. It will just moderate itself. In the question I mention at the beginning, the category "unclear what you're asking" was just used to give that user a lecture for asking too casually. I don't think that was a correct close. I would remove those categories and additionally, give moderators an option to edit/write the reason why they are voting for closing.

I don't know all the details how moderation works because I don't have these rights. I am just expressing a certain dissatisfaction with the system as one of the users being moderated.

EDIT: I accept that the comment deletion should have happened. It was rushed of me to put it into this post. Closing the question is the thing that I mind.

Comment: How the hell is that comment helpful? Why the hell should it stick around?

Comment: FWIW the entire comment thread was purged about 7 hours after the question had been reopened. So even if your comment had been a more constructive approach to reopening, it would still have been obsolete at the time the moderator reviewed the post. As an aside - when we run across long threads of comments which contain many that need to be deleted, we tend not to go picking through them all to try and find specific ones to keep.

Comment: The question was reopened, therefore your comment had the effect you wanted and was now outdated; where's the problem?

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps the question should not have been closed in the first place. However, consider this: Stack Overflow gets 7,000+ questions a day. Many (most?) of them are garbage in one way or another. The need to moderate this huge influx has lead to a certain narrow-mindedness, and trigger-happiness, in the SO audience: you need to prove, visibly, that you are asking an actual, serious question. If you don't, you get closed down quickly - rightly or wrongly. (Mostly rightly.)  The closing of a question that looks as vague/unfocused like this one will occasionally happen and that the onus of editing it and getting it reopened is on the OP.

That's just the way it is - Stack Overflow is a big city these days.

Re the comment deletions - long off-topic comment discussions (or discussions that derail into flaming and such, which is what may have happened here, I can't see the deleted comments) are frequently deleted by moderators as a well-publicized and normal cleanup measure. While I can see how one might see this deletion as something sinister, rest assured it was  not.

Comment: For some perspective I don't think it helped that the OP had a previous poor quality question and in this nor the previous case did the OP make an effort to improve it.

Comment: Ye, well, I just know (from my own experience too) that closing a question can generate lots of frustration. SO is the most useful site ever but sometimes it seems a bit over-serious. More contact with the moderators that decide on closing would be nice (either from their side or from OP's side).

Comment: "More contact with the moderators would be nice." This is what Meta is for @clime. Wrong closures happen, we can't get it right _every_ time. Just post a constructive inquiry about the closure, and more often than not the question will be re-opened in minutes. Also, no moderator was involved in closing the question, five regular users closed it.

Comment: @clime I don't think that's feasible with the amounts of traffic the site is seeing. The OP can edit their question and petition for reopening (as seems to have happened in this case).

Comment: Yannis: where should I put that inquiry, in the comments? Will be the people that closed it notified? Or should I flag it and choose "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)"? I tried that once but nothing happened.

Comment: @probablyPekka:  I think, it would be good that instead of using categories, a user that votes to close would leave a short note as a close reason. These notes would be then displayed in the grey box. This way the end user always gets the feedback he needs and it is much more human approach. People might be polite in the notes and the reasons will be clearer.

Answer (score 6):

To chip in here, I was the one who removed those comments. Multiple comments on that question were flagged as either being obsolete or rude. All of the comments were either criticizing the reason it was closed, or responding to that criticism, and none of that applied any longer once the question had been edited and reopened. The comments at that point distracted from the question being asked, so I decided to clear all of them away.

As far as why the question was closed in the first place, the original wording of that question was:

> What is wrong with this C++ code? (short code)
>
> [code here]
>
> The answer? A SMILEY FACE (WTF!?) - Not joking, the answer actually is a smiley
>   face...

That wasn't exactly the best-phrased question, and I could see why some people voted to close it as not being clear what was asked. Thus the arguments in the comments.

When it was rephrased to

> [code here]
>
> Why does this code output a smiley face when ran?

it became a lot clearer as to what the point of the question was, and it was reopened as a result.

In my opinion, the community functioned as intended in this case by placing a question on hold as being unclear, clarifying it, then reopening it as a result. The comments about this process were no longer needed at the end of it, and we are now left with only a targeted question and a good answer.

Comment: Except one small problem that the person who edited/corrected the question wasn't OP but the guy that answered it.

Comment: One more important thing and perhaps a point I should have mentioned. If the question was closed before that guy tried to answer, the thread could stay without any answers and on on-hold/closed forever. But probably he would edited it and then wait for it to be reopened. So the whole process would just cause trouble to the person that tried to answer. Not at all ideal.

Comment: I don't mind deleting comments anymore. I accept that as perfectly allright. I was just affected.

Comment: @clime Why is it a problem that the person who improved the question wasn't the OP?  That's a feature of the site that the OP doesn't (always) need to be the one to fix the question.  If the question *isn't* improved enough to meet the site's guidelines then yes, it can stay closed forever.  Again, that's by design.  If it's closed in error, it just needs some attention to be reopened; that's something that tends to happen in most cases.

Comment: @Servy I just say that sometimes closing a question is counter-productive - it prevents answers to appear. Why should people that want to answer be prevented to do that? In case of off-topic/opinion-based questions...sure. But "question isn't clear or too broad". Ok, then it's a bad question and not much people will bother to answer. But maybe it is just seemingly flawed - and in fact, it might be interesting which cannot be seen at quick look as it happened in this case and I have this experience too. These two categories just forces people "to behave" but it doesn't need to be forced.

Comment: @clime The problem is that lots of people try to answer low quality questions that they shouldn't answer.  These answers tend to be of very low quality themselves, and create further problems in trying to improve the question.  For unclear questions people tend to just make up a bunch of assumptions and answer based on what they think might be the case, rather than what is the case.  If they guess wrong, it causes problems.  For too broad questions the issue isn't that you can't answer, it's that everyone wants to answer and the question is flooded with low quality answers.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if it goes as you describe. But surely you and people here have experience with it. Statistics on activity of such questions (that would be "normally" marked like that) would be nice though. If it works as you describe, these two close reasons make sense. One question, if I leave a comment below the question that was closed, will be the people that closed it notified? If so, I think that this could at least be mentioned in that gray box or somewhere so that people know they can do something if they think the question was closed inappropriately.